# Распознавание животных на аэрофотоснимках

Tags: распознавание-образов

Имеется коллекция изображений размером 5184x3156, полученных в процессе аэрофотосъёмки, на которых необходимо распознать степных сайгаков. Примеры входных данных: [№1](https://pp.vk.me/c620128/v620128226/24449/CKdOCXcHWnU.jpg), [№2](https://pp.vk.me/c620128/v620128226/24452/V0m8r0l5dls.jpg), [№3](https://pp.vk.me/c620128/v620128226/2445b/m1FMd9KE2zk.jpg).

С подобной задачей сталкиваюсь впервые — буду благодарен, если посоветуете способы решения проблемы (в какую область нужно копать, с чего можно подступиться). Также буду рад ссылкам на любые готовые программные решения смежных задач.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каких-либо конкретных методов решения задачи не могу дать, но однозначно необходимо применять коррелятор двумерного изображения. В качестве алгоритмов использовать быстрый алгоритм взаимной корреляции (на основе БПФ).

С уважением, maxspb89.

Comment: Не совсем понял задачу, думал, что нужна автоматическая распознавалка в реальном времени. )

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Photoshop Extended помогает [считать объекты в изображении](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/counting-objects-image-photoshop-extended.html). Два варианта:

- ручной режим: кликать мышкой по каждому найденному глазами сайгаку;
- автоматический: подсчитает количество выделенных областей. Надо обработать картинку фильтрами и настройками уровней и т.п. так, чтобы сайгаки отличались от всего остального, например, цветом (фон белый, они черные, но при этом черные только они). Это вполне можно сделать. Затем выбор по цвету (чёрный), и автоматически подсчитать количество отдельных выделенных областей. При однородности изображений достаточно один раз настроить такую обработку, и можно анализировать изображения пачкой.

**Как бы я обрабатывал картинку:**

- выбрал из трёх каналов тот, в котором сайкаги наиболее контрастны, и дальше работал только с ним;
- [методом частотного разложения](http://zhur74.livejournal.com/998.html) выделил объекты размера сайгаков в отдельный слой;
- уровнями, фильтром Find Edges или другими добился белого фона без "мусора" и черных пятен сайгаков;
- Select - Color range - выбрать все чёрные области:
- сосчитать их.

При одинаковом масштабе снимков (и размере сайгаков на них) можно загнать всю последовательность действий в File - Automate - Batch... и применить ко всем изображениям в папке.